# ¿Si se borra una librería que utilizamos mediante 'implementation' en Gradle que pasaría? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-glide

Tenemos un proyecto Android en Android Studio y utiliza una serie de librerías que se han implementado en el proyecto mediante esta cita en Gradle, por ejemplo:

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Como vemos, se implementa remotamente.

Pero... y que pasaría si por ejemplo en un futuro se borra?

Este 'tag' o 'link' dejaría de funcionar y ya no me dejaría compilar...

Si es así, el proyecto se puede ir al traste si depende librerías complejas de terceros.

Comment: Principalmente debes revisar si la Library que usas tiene soporte.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad al agregar la dependencia en tu `build.gradle` lo que sucede es que esta se descarga, localmente:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

al tenerla localmente, cuando construyes tu proyecto se agrega al mismo, por lo que no importarìa si la url de donde se obtiene dejara de funcionar.

Es importante revisar si la dependencia que deseas agregar tiene soporte, si no tiene soporte probablemente el desarrolador dejara de realizar actualizaciones al repositorio. En el caso de `Glide` por ejemplo es una library de Google, muy usada actualmente, seguramente continuaran las actualizaciones.